# Flutter toJson missing semicolon

Tags: json, flutter, api

I have following model class.

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Login {
  String? userName;
  String? password;

  Login({required this.userName, required this.password});

  factory Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LoginFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LoginToJson(this);
}
```

Generated part file.

```
Login _$LoginFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Login(
      userName: json['userName'] as String?,
      password: json['password'] as String?,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$LoginToJson(Login instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'userName': instance.userName,
      'password': instance.password,
    };
```

when i try to use it to post to api with follow code

```
  Future<void> loginUser(Login login) async => {
        print(login.toJson().toString());
}
```

**Result from the print statement (cause convertion error)**

```
{userName: test, password: password}
```

***Expecting valid json to post is***

```
{
  "username": "string",
  "password": "string"
}
```

**Error Message**

```
Error: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of '_HashSet<String>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `=>` from

```
Future<void> loginUser(Login login) async => {
  print(login.toJson().toString());
}
```

to

```
Future<void> loginUser(Login login) async {
  print(login.toJson().toString());
}
```

In the first example, it is an arrow function where the brackets `{ }` stand for a set literal since it's right after the arrow, much like in the generated `_$LoginToJson` function but without describing the types of the set.

In the second example, it is a normal function the brackets `{ }` define the body of the function.

You might be looking to call `jsonEncode` (`import dart:convert;`) which takes a value, such as a `Map<String, dynamic>` and turns it into a `String` in json format.

Update the print statement as follows:

```
print(jsonEncode(login.toJson()));
```

While the generated functions parse the object to a format that is suitable for JSON, it doesn't turn it into an actual `String`. You'll need to encode it with `jsonEncode`. Similarly, when processing a JSON response, you'll need to `jsonDecode` the response body to get a `Map<String, dynamic>` structure that you can then pass into the generated `fromJson` functions.

Comment: what is wrong with this. I removed. and it is still showing the same thing

Comment: The error message wasn't part of the question at time of this answer. I updated the answer to explain why, but I think it might be another issue.

Comment: this is strange. so basically I use reactive_form. I check the form.value. there is no semi column as well.

Comment: I don't understand how you are getting an DioError from this code sample. Dio isn't called in the sample

Comment: I think you need to use `jsonEncode` on the Map<String, dynamic> before you get an actual JSON string. Updated the answer

Comment: actually, there is line below print statement to call dio, but i removed it. dio.post('account/login', data: {jsonEncode(login.toJson())});

Comment: you are right. jsonEncode works. can you explain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245192/discussion-between-sras-and-dumazy).